# Using embeddings to anonymize information

Tags: word-embeddings, llm

This might be a stupid question, so bear with me.
I was wondering if embeddings can be used to anonymize input text.
I couldn't find any information online that says that embeddings can be 1:1 decoded back to the original text.

An example:
A user wants to check some metadata about a query with an external API, but doesn't want the exact text input to be sent to the API (it might contain sensitive information).

Can he send the embeddings to the API, assuming the API can do meaningful checks on the embeddings - so the API will not have access to the original text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embeddings encode the data but do nothing to encrypt it and give no guarantees of security. If you want to encrypt the data but be able to do mathematical operations you can use something like [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption). With embeddings used for this purpose, the attacker could backward engineer them and deduce the encoded text.

If you want to know more on why this is a bad idea and how homomorphic encryption helps, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'll ask there, thanks!